# How to copy specific number of characters from each line from one file to another

Tags: c

So I'm trying to write a program that takes 3 command line arguments, 1. The name of an existing file, 2. The name of the new file, 3. The number of characters to copy from each line to the new file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int size = atoi(argv[3]); // The number of characters to copy 
    char content[size];
    char line[size];

    FILE *f1 = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // Read from first file                                                          
    FILE *f2 = fopen(argv[2], "w"); // Write to second file                                                          

    if (f1 == NULL || f2 == NULL) {
        printf("\nThere was an error reading the file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(content, size, f1) != NULL) {
        // This is what I had first:
        fprintf(f2, "%s", content);                                                                                 

        // And when that didn't work, I tried this:
        strncpy(line, content, size);
        fprintf(f2, "%s", line);                                                                                           
    }

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Please indicate the expected output example.

Comment: Wouldn't argv start from argv[0] and not argv[1] ?

Comment: So if a line from the read file is: 'Today I went on a run' and the value of size, which is the number of characters I want to read it, is 7, then the output file would be 'Today I'. But for every line of the read file. And argv[0] would be the name of the command, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how `fgets` is working.  It's designed to read up the end of the next line *or* a maximum number of `size` characters, whichever comes first.  If it reads `size` characters before reading a newline character, it returns that `size`-length string, but it leaves the rest of the line in the input stream, ready to be read by the next `fgets` call!  So, if `size` is 10, your loop just reads long lines in 10 character chunks but still outputs the full line, 10 characters at a time.

If you want to keep the structure of your current program, the trick will be to use `fgets` to read in a full line (using a buffer and `size` value that's longer than the longest possible line), remove the newline if it's present, truncate the line to `n` characters (by NUL-terminating it, say), and print out the shortened line.

Is that enough of a hint, or did you just want a working example?

Edit:  Okay, here's one working solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char line[4096];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int size = atoi(argv[3]); // The number of characters to copy

    FILE *f1 = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // Read from first file
    FILE *f2 = fopen(argv[2], "w"); // Write to second file

    if (f1 == NULL || f2 == NULL) {
        printf("\nThere was an error reading the file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // read whole line
    // note: if the whole line doesn't fit in 4096 bytes,
    // we'll be treating it as multiple 4096-byte lines
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f1) != NULL) {

        // NUL-terminate at "size" bytes
        // (no effect if already less than that)
        line[size] = '\0';

        // write up to newline or NUL terminator
        for (char* p = line; *p && *p != '\n'; ++p) {
            putc(*p, f2);
        }
        putc('\n', f2);

    }

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get what you're saying, but isn't that what the strncpy line would be doing? Basically copying the full line read in, to a new line, and then writing that to the write file?

Comment: Let's say you're reading a file with a single line of 10000 characters with `size` set to 10.  Here's what your loop does with the `strncpy` version in place:  (1) using `fgets`, read the next 9 characters from `f1` into the `content` buffer and NUL terminate it for a total of 10 characters; (2) using `strncpy`, copy those 9 characters plus the NUL terminator from `content` to `line`; (3) print those 9 characters to `f2`; and (4) loop back to the beginning to get the next 9 characters.

Comment: Hmm, okay I see. If it's no trouble, do you mind posting a working solution?